# Chrome or Firefox render pdf's much better than Evince's

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince

Chrome or Firefox render pdf's much better than Evince's (ubuntu's default pdf viewer).
For example
Chrome:

[image]

Evince:

[image]

Both pictures are taken at same zoom and even if perhaps you might not notice difference in the images (due to screenshot upload quality and so on), there is a noticeable difference.
What is it that chrome is doing right and evince is not?  How can I fix this?
I really love Evince otherwise and it is so convenient to use.

**Update**: It seems that https://github.com/zhou13/poppler-subpixel will help in my case. But I do not know how to implement these patches. So answer explaining how to do that will be helpful.
Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: See Wikipedia: [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

Comment: I think the Evince one looks sharper.

Comment: @xiota you are absolutely right. Chrome text looks smoother to me. Anyway what I was hoping for was that someone would know that perhaps the rendering methods are different (mostly you do because you linked the wikipedia article) and how to force evince to render in chrome's way.

Answer (score 1):

The image from Chrome appears to have [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) enabled, while the one from Evince does not.

- Some people do not like subpixel rendering because it addes red and blue edges to either side of glyphs.
- Subpixel rendering is less beneficial on higher resolution displays.

While you can "enable" subpixel rendering system-wide, it's really only a *suggestion*. It's ultimately up to each application or library to implement subpixel rendering or not. In this case, it appears the Poppler library does not currently support subpixel rendering.

There are a couple related issues in Poppler's git repository that have been open for years. I wouldn't expect any progress anytime soon.

- [[patch] add support for subpixel rendering support for cairo backend](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/23) (4 years)
- [subpixel-hinted rendering of text with poppler](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/61) (15 years)